# I have design pattern in which i have to divide 12 bootsrap in to 9 and 3 so please see the image?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have design pattern in which i have to divide 12 bootsrap in to 9 and 3 so i did but the question is aga more in under 9 column div i have to put 4 more div with 9 width so what i should do ?? [image]

selectall

```
                                    <div class = "col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 firstcheck  ">
                                         <span><input type="checkbox" name="date" value="date1"> selectall
                                                    </span>

                                        </div>
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/goPaperLess.jpg" alt="PaperLess" >
                                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                                            <div class ="imagefoteer">
                                            </div>

                                </div>
```

Comment: Are you asking what you should do about the row in the middle with "Account Number", "Service Address", etc.? If so, what problem are you having putting four divs there? Your question is unclear. Please [edit] it to clarify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is put your 4 new rows inside the

```
<div class = "col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 firstcheck  ">
...
 </div>
```

By doing this all the elements you add to the col-9 row will have the containers max width. You can even create a row inside the col-9 div to further divide the div into divs with col- * - * sizes.

```css
.fluid-container{margin: 0px 10px;}
.border{ border: 1px solid gray;}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fluid-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="well">
        Your content
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        Your content
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        Your content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="well">
          The sidebar
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```